# How to pass date time string to remote database through oracle database link?

Tags: sql, datetime, oracle10g, birt

I use database link to query data from remote database view. When I apply local time to gmt time conversion [Query 2] sql performance is become very slow. I prefer to do the gmt date conversion in remote database. Is there anyway to pass the date string to remote database?

```
[Query-1]
    SELECT *
    FROM v_captured_details@DL_REMOTE
    WHERE CAPTURE_TIME_GMT BETWEEN
            (TO_DATE(&STARTDATE, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')) AND (TO_DATE(&ENDDATE, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'));


[Query-2]
    SELECT *
    FROM v_captured_details@DL_REMOTE
    WHERE CAPTURE_TIME_GMT BETWEEN
           GMT_TIME_DATE(TO_DATE(&STARTDATE, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')) AND GMT_TIME_DATE(TO_DATE(&ENDDATE, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'));
```

This data need to be populated in BIRT report with local database data. Do not like to do the local to gmt conversion in BIRT.

Comment: Assuming that `gmt_time_date` is some BIRT function, your last couple sentences don't make sense to me.  You say that you don't want to do the local to GMT conversion in BIRT but that's what you seem to be doing here.  Unless `GMT_TIME_DATE` is a PL/SQL function that you've defined locally.  Do you just want to avoid a PL/SQL function that returns a `SYS_REFCURSOR`?  Rather than avoiding all PL/SQL functions in the query?

Comment: Yes, gmt_time_date is a PL/SQL function defined in local database.

Comment: Do you have to use that function?  Or could you take the logic from the function and incorporate it into the query so that the function can be evaluated on the remote machine?  Could you create the function on the remote machine?  Is `gmt_time_date` defined as deterministic?  Is it actually deterministic?

Comment: I have a function in remote database. How do I pass the date string to remote database? If I convert the column CAPTURE_TIME_GMT to local in remote database it also become very slow.

Comment: @JustinCave I removed the cursor part, I think, Cursor cannot be used in BIRT template.